# Casting non-0-based array created by c# Array.CreateInstance to collection T

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, casting, zero

I'm trying to convert vb6 code to c# code.
My vb6 source code contains arrays of the most varied types and after conversion by Vs2005 tools these arrays have become 0-based array, but I need to reconvert to non-0-based array.So for example I try to use Array.CreateInstance with explicit cast to T[] for a generic use:

```
public void ResizeArrayBaseN<T>(ref T[] original, int firstLower, int firstCount)
{
    try
    {
        int[] myBoundsArray = new int[1] {firstLower };
        int[] myLengthsArray = new int[1] {firstCount - firstLower + 1 };
        original = (T[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), myLengthsArray, myBoundsArray);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But I'm catching cast from T[*] to T[] error.
Can someone help me,please ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

A `T[]` is a *vector* array - a zero-based one-dimensional array. You **cannot** use `T[]` to represent an array with a non-zero base, because: it isn't a vector. This is what the `*` in `T[*]` means. I suspect it can *only* be referenced as an `Array` - making it quite inconvenient to use.